# Repeating a string several times in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to answer to the following interview question in java and it looks like they don't like my answer (see below) anyone could be kind enough to explain me why it doesn't work? Thank you!

> Given a string and a non-negative int n, we'll say that the front of the string is the first 3 chars, or whatever is there if the string is less than length 3. Return n copies of the front;
>
> ```
> frontTimes("Chocolate", 2) → "ChoCho"
> frontTimes("Chocolate", 3) → "ChoChoCho"
> frontTimes("Abc", 3) → "AbcAbcAbc"
> ```

And this is my code:

```
public String frontTimes(String str, int n) {
    String part = str.substring(0,3);
    String result = part.repeat(n);
    return result;
}
```

and this is their solution:

```
public String frontTimes(String str, int n) {
    int frontLen = 3;
    if (frontLen > str.length()) {
        frontLen = str.length();
    }
    String front = str.substring(0, frontLen);
    
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        result = result + front;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `String.repeat` isn't a method, and `String.substring(0, 3)` would fail if the string is shorter than 3 characters.

Comment: Marks off for the interviewer not using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: There is StringUtils.repeat. Also, it might be acceptable to throw an exception if the input string is too short. I don't see the point in preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

Most fundamentally, `String` doesn't have a `repeat` method, so `part.repeat(n)` simply wouldn't compile.

There is also a runtime bug in that `str.substring(0, 3)` would fail if `str` had fewer than 3 characters.

I wouldn't describe the model solution as perfect, however.

- They could simply have used `int frontLen = Math.min(3, str.length());`, which is a lot more readable.
- `result` should be accumulated in a `StringBuilder` to avoid repeated string construction:

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(front.length() * n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    sb.append(front);
  }
  return sb.toString();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Andy's answer pretty much covers what was incorrect. However, instead of asking what is not right, you could simply write some unit tests to check whether your code works as intended:

```
@Test
public void testFrontTimesMethod() {
    Assert.assertEquals("ChoCho", frontTimes("Chocolate", 2));
    Assert.assertEquals("ChoChoCho", frontTimes("Chocolate", 3));
    Assert.assertEquals("AbcAbcAbc", frontTimes("Abc", 3));
    Assert.assertEquals("AbAbAbAbAbAbAbAbAbAb", frontTimes("Ab", 10));
    Assert.assertEquals("", frontTimes("", 5));
}
```